# tf.reduce_sum on GPU fails in combination with placeholder as input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

**UPDATE**:
Fixed in Tensorflow 1.14.0 (maybe earlier, didn't check)

**UPDATE**:
Still occurring in Tensorflow 1.7.0

**UPDATE**:
I wrote a collab notebook that reproduces this bug on google's gpu hardware: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13V87kSTyyFVMM7NoJNk9QTsCYS7FRbyz/view?usp=sharing

**UPDATE**:
After wrongly accusing `tf.gather` in the first revisions of this question I now narrowed it down to `tf.reduce_sum` in combination with a placeholder as shape:

`tf.reduce_sum` produces zeros (on GPU only) for large tensors whose shape depends on a placeholder.

Running the following code while feeding a large integer to placeholder `batch_size` (>700000 in my case):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[])
    ones_with_placeholder = tf.ones([batch_size,256,4])
    sum_out = tf.reduce_sum(ones_with_placeholder,axis=2)
    min_sum_out = tf.reduce_min(sum_out)

sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)

sum_result,min_sum_result = sess.run([sum_out,min_sum_out],feed_dict={batch_size: 1000000})
print("Min value in sum_out processed on host with numpy:", np.min(sum_result))
print("Min value in sum_out tensor processed in graph with tf:", min_sum_result)
```

The following, wrong result is shown:

```
Min value in sum_out processed on host with numpy: 0.0
Min value in sum_out tensor processed in graph with tf: 0.0
```

I was expecting that applying `reduce_sum` over axis 2 should result in 4.0 everywhere!

Running this exact code on CPU leads to correct results. Also running this with a fixed shape for tf.ones leads to the correct results on both CPU and GPU:

```
ones_with_fixed_shape = tf.ones([1000000,256,4])
sum_out = tf.reduce_sum(ones_with_fixed_shape,axis=2)
```

What is the problem with the placeholder on GPU?

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying comment on my proposed answer. I think it would be really beneficial if you edit the question to have a deterministic (not random) case where this behaviour occurs. It might be a bug but needs a concrete, easily reproducible example to verify if that is the case.

Comment: Yes I was just playing around with it and it seems like it is not the gather function but the reduce sum function (see the update). So I'm new to stackoverflow, should I reopen the question for tf.reduce_sum or change the title of this question?

Comment: IMO the best thing you can do is edit out the (now unnecessary) details, update the title and provide a concise code snippet that allows anyone to reproduce the problem simply by copy-pasting. I am certain you will find an answer to the question then :)

Comment: thanks, I narrowed it down further and hopefully simplified the question

Comment: It seems to be related to the datatype of the array of ones. I tried with: `ones_with_placeholder = tf.ones([batch_size,256,4], dtype=tf.int64)` and got the expected result. The default type used if one is not explicitly specified is `tf.float32`. Could this be a numerical overflow issue?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that, if tf.ones are of type int32 or int64 it works as expected. But it still doesn't work for tf.ones with dtype float32 and float64. But you can confirm this problem in general?

Comment: Yes, I was able to replicate the problem with the code you provided. I am very curious what the reason for this behaviour is! I edited to add the couple of `import` statements so now anyone can try it literally by just copy pasting.

Comment: Yes I noticed, thanks. I'm relieved now. I was hunting this stupid bug for a day now and was already worried that the problem lies specifically within my development setup. But now it sounds like it's a problem for the guys at google

Comment: With a bit of experimentation, it does work up to 524,288 (2 ^ 19) fed in your code, fails for 524,289, which would put the max ok size of the placeholder to 2 ^ ( 19 + 10 (256 x 4) + 2 ( for float32 ) = 2 ^ 31, which suspiciously looks like they are okay up to a size that can be stored in an int32.

Comment: Specifying the data type resolved the issue for me: 
`ones_with_placeholder = tf.ones([batch_size,256,4], dtype=tf.int32)`

Comment: We discussed this before: It works for int32 and int64, but fails for float32 and float64

Comment: Looks like this might be an [Eigen issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/reduction_ops_sum.cc#L45). Since you have verified that this is replicated on multiple machines it probably warrants  an issue on the tensorflow github.

Comment: I can reproduce this bug in Tensorflow 1.12.0 by the code provided by OP

Comment: The problem was fixed with this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22123

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that there's a speed/accuracy tradeoff. Even though your example seems trivial, with the entire tensor initialized to 1, there are 1.024B entries. Note that int32 can represent integral numbers in the range
[-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647] without loss of precison:

So we expect to see some error if we accumulate all of the entries and perform computation. This also explains why smaller matrices didn't exhibit the problem(smaller Batch size).

Comment: No thats not the problem here. If you take a look at `sum_out`, it is correct (all 4.0s) up to a certain threshold in the first dimension (dependent on `batch_size`), BUT the last entries of `sum_out` are all zeros. So this is not a loss of precision, it is a hard fail. At least if you want to calculate block error rates like I do...